# Incompatible numeric format between points and polygons geometry in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, point-in-polygon, geodataframe

I am reproducing an exercise on GeoPandas. Basically, I want to check whether points are within a given polygon. However, polygon format numbers are quite different. They seem huge (possibly because number format).

Below is the polygon sample file:

```
ID   ALUEJAKO KUNTA TUNNUS  ... YHTDATANOMISTAJA  KOKOTUNNUS  PAIVITETTY_TIETOPALVELUUN                                           geometry
0  112859  SUURPIIRI   091      1  ...    Helsinki/Kami  0911000000                 2021-01-14  POLYGON ((25487917.082 6665229.637, 25489108.9...
1  112860  SUURPIIRI   091      2  ...    Helsinki/Kami  0912000000                 2021-01-14  POLYGON ((25490664.517 6682390.219, 25490679.6...
```

And below is the point sample file:

```
                                              address                   geometry
0   Ruoholahti, 14, Itämerenkatu, Salmisaari, Ruoh...  POINT (24.91556 60.16320)
1   Kamppi, 1, Kampinkuja, Kamppi, Eteläinen suurp...  POINT (24.93166 60.16905)
2   Kauppakeskus Citycenter, 8, Kaivokatu, Keskust...  POINT (24.94179 60.16989)
3   Hermannin rantatie, Verkkosaari, Kalasatama, S...  POINT (24.97846 60.19032)
```

How can I fix the polygon number format so that they have the same magnitude of point geometries?

Comment: You need to make sure both your data sets are in the same projection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Reproject](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) so the dataframes are in the same crs:

> Transform all geometries in an active geometry column to a different
> coordinate reference system

I want both in EPSG:4326:

```
print(poly.head(2))
# 0  POLYGON ((477348.792 7102750.977, 478052.285 7...
# 1  POLYGON ((580456.811 7153766.246, 581279.773 7...

print(point.head(2))             
#id                   geometry
# 0  0.0  POINT (14.26245 63.54284)
# 1  1.0  POINT (18.88441 62.26180)

print(poly.crs)
#EPSG:3006
print(point.crs)
#EPSG:4326

poly = poly.to_crs(point.crs) #Or poly = poly.to_crs(epsg="4326")
print(poly.head(2))
#                                             geometry
# 0  POLYGON ((14.53606 64.05074, 14.55047 64.05073...
# 1  POLYGON ((16.67505 64.49975, 16.69217 64.49949...
```

Comment: More information about EPSGs, one can find here: https://epsg.org/home.html